# Cannot use the ' character

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am trying to send a message to a user, but when I use the `'` in a message, it gives me this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '0','16-03-2016','16:25:28','51')' at line 1

So this means I cannot use `'` because the code is written with the `'` character.

```
INSERT INTO trofee (van,voor,bericht,trofee,datum,tijd,user_id) VALUES ('".htmlentities($gegevens['gebruikersnaam'])."','".$_POST['voor']."','".$_POST['bericht']."','".$_POST['trofee']."','" . date("d-m-Y") . "','" . date("H:i:s") . "','".htmlentities($gegevens['id'])."')
```

How can I enable the use of `'` in SQL queries?

Comment: "How can I enable the use of ' in SQL queries?" - Use parameters instead of concatenating strings into a SQL statement.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is an administrative tool to manage databases — not a database system itself, so I removed that tag and added the correct tag for your database.

Answer (score 2):

If the value contains `'` you should replace each occurrence by `''` from back end or from SQL (not double quote `"`, but 2 times single quote).